# Are there specific valid table names in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I initially intended to just try and get myself familiar with the use of Sqlite in android but I ended up getting stucked trying to fix an error that doesn't exist in the first place.

I created a table with the name "table", but whenever I try to get data from the table the app crashes and moreover data saved to the table doesn't get saved(but I never knew).

After few hours of trying to fix things I changed the table name and it worked well.

My question is **Is "table" not a valid Table name in sqlite like some sort of keywords** if so then any link to othet sql keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes table is a keyword in sqlite. You can check the keywords [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Also sqlite  keywords are not case sensitive so typing "table" or any other keyword either way will mean the same thing.

Comment: Cheers!! have a nice day

Comment: Also consider marking my answer as the correct answer!! :D